# How can I use jquery to get a hover effect to work on ajaxed data?

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

I have the following jquery script that works fine when I view a particular webpage. This webpage allows me to change the data via ajax. The problem is that when I "ajax in" some new data, the script no longer works on this new data. Why?

Jquery:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('body').on('hover','.hover_class',function(){
        $(this).find('.class1').css('background-color','#000000');
        $(this).find('.class2').stop().addClass('my_class',400);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).find('.class1').css('background-color','#ffffff');
        $(this).find('.class2').removeClass("my_class",100);
    }
    );
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('mouseenter', '.hover_class', function () {
        $(this).find('.class1').css('background-color', '#000000');
        $(this).find('.class2').stop().addClass('my_class');
    }).on('mouseleave', '.hover_class', function () {
        $(this).find('.class1').css('background-color', '#ffffff');
        $(this).find('.class2').removeClass("my_class");
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes. That's it!. Thanks so much. I'm not exactly sure why ``mouseenter`` and ``mouseleave`` work, and ``hover`` doesn't. Either way, thanks for the help!